# Firebase database permission denied error

Tags: javascript, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I am making an app that displays events. I created a page which shows the summaries of the events with a link to the full event details. I read in the docs that database objects can be retrieved by adding .json to the URL (https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/rest/database/).  My app uses JavaScript to construct the links to each object, however when the link is clicked, I get a permission denied error even when I am signed into the app as a user. Does anyone know how to resolve this? 
I have a demo of the app here on Codepen: https://codepen.io/heresnova/pen/VWoxXr. Note you'll have to refresh the page after logging into the app to view the content.

Basically what I'm trying to do is create a "read more" link to an expanded view of the full database object. Does anyone know how to do this with Firebase?

Here's the relevant JavaScript code:

```
var events = firebase.database().ref("events");

    // displays event listings 
    events.on('value', function(snapshot) {
        snapshot.forEach(function(childSnapshot) {
        var eventkey = childSnapshot.key;
        var eventdata = childSnapshot.val();
        var browseId = eventkey.toString(); 
        var showcards = document.getElementById('showcards');

        // listing data to be displayed
        var browseTitle = childSnapshot.val().title;
        var browseDate = childSnapshot.val().starttime;
        var browseCity = childSnapshot.val().city;
        var browseCost = childSnapshot.val().price;
        var dbUrl = "https://authtest-54513.firebaseio.com/events/";
        var addJson = ".json";
        var evUrl = dbUrl+eventkey+addJson;
          // event card
        var card = document.createElement('div');
        card.setAttribute('class', 'card'); // assign class card to div for css styling
        showcards.appendChild(card);


          // display all listings on page
        var cardtitle = document.createElement('p'); 
          cardtitle.setAttribute('id', 'evdata'); 
        cardtitle.innerHTML = browseTitle + " " + " " + browseCity + " " + "&pound;" + browseCost;
        card.appendChild(cardtitle);  

          var showUrl = document.createElement('a');
          showUrl.setAttribute('href', evUrl);
         // showUrl.innerHTML = "more...";
          showUrl.innerHTML = evUrl;
          card.appendChild(showUrl);

        console.log(eventdata);
  });  // end foreach childSnapshot function
}); // end events.on function
```

My security rules:

```
{
  "rules": {
    ".read": "auth != null",
    ".write": "auth != null",
      "user-events": {
        ".indexOn": ["uid"],
        "$uid": {
          ".read": "auth != null && auth.uid == $uid",
          ".write": "auth != null && auth.uid == $uid"
        }
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you make a request through the firebase SDK it keeps the auth state by passing with each request a token, a piece of information that contains information about your session. You can see an example of this in the simulator when you toggle `authenticated`.

When you try to open a direct link like `https://authtest-54513.firebaseio.com/events/-KnP3MkFt5559uP1w5fh.json` you are making a GET request but you are not passing any token to verify your identity, so this won't work if your security rules prevent any action from users who are not authenticated (`auth != null`).

Anyway, I think this is a very weird thing to do, the json available at `https://authtest-54513.firebaseio.com/events/-KnP3MkFt5559uP1w5fh.json` contains the same data that you have in your variable `eventdata`. 
You could just use `JSON.stringify(eventdata)` to get the same string you would see clicking the link, or iterate `eventdata` as a javascript object and create a nice html template.

Developing an app you don't usually need to use the [REST API](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/rest/database/), but if you want to use them you may want to take a look at the [auth section](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/rest/database/user-auth)

Comment: Thanks Devid. If I use JSON stringify, how do I achieve the "read more" link? I was using the REST API because I wanted the user to be taken to a new page to view the full object details. Is there another way to do this? I posted a question here because I used a modal but it only showed the first object: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44968983/modal-displaying-firebase-data-only-displays-first-object

Comment: I just added the user's token to the GET request but now receive "Unauthorized request" error.

Comment: I'll take a look at the other question later today ;) For the `unauthorized request` please create another question since that is a different problem and you should provide some more data. If this answers your initial question, please consider accepting it ;)

Comment: Do you have an example of this part of your answer? "iterate eventdata as a javascript object and create a nice html template."